# Form to find value's position in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, function, indexof

I am trying to create a form that takes only a single letter and finds its position in an array (which is essentially the alphabet).

I wrote some this simple code:

```
var alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
var letter = "h";
var letterPosition = alphabet.indexOf(letter);

document.write(letterPosition);
```

to demonstrate the basic function. However, I am not sure how to put this into a `function get` and make the `var letter` equal to the value in the form's input.

I want this to return the location in the array so that I can write a loop (inside an if/else)that will print all values in the array that come after the input value.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? There are better ways of accomplishing what you ask providing that they conform with your real problem.

Comment: @HansBPUFAL Here is the full scenario: I will have an editable table cell, someone will enter a letter into it, based on that letter all cells following it will be updated to the subsequent letters until "z" or the number of cells run out. I figured the alphabet array could be used in a `for` loop to accomplish this. I have been trying to write each part independent of the other and then make them work together once i get a better grasp on each part. Maybe this isn't the best method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `alphabet[alphabet.indexOf(letter)]` or in your code `alphabet[letterPosition]`

Concerning the *loop* you mentioned: with that value you can use the `slice` method to give you a subset of remaining characters from the `alphabet` array (ergo: no need for a loop to determine the remainder of elements from your array):

```
var subset = alphabet.slice(indexOf([a letter]));
```

And just to save you some typing: you could also declare your alphabet array like this:

```
var alphabet 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
```

Comment: You are my hero. I changed the slice to `var subset = alphabet.slice(letterPosition+1, 26);` and it works great. Now on to the next step!..

Answer (score 2):

Build a demo
http://jsbin.com/ijuco4

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the context, is this loading with the page (no AJAX involved)?  I may be oversimplifying:

```
<input type="text" id="whichLetter" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function getLetterPosition(allLetters, letter)
{
  return allLetters.indexOf(letter);
}

var alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
var letter = document.getElementById("whichLetter").value;
var letterPosition = getLetterPosition(alphabet, letter);

</script>
```

i love javascript.

Comment: Uhh ya, completely did not understand the question - my bad, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

or you could do

```
let alphabetPosition = (text) => text.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '').split('').map(ch => ch.charCodeAt(0) - 64).join(' ');
```